# How to check for no input in bash read?

Tags: bash

I am looking for a conditional to avoid users from leaving an input value blank. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No inputs (or even spaces I believe) get entered as empty strings, so check input while the input var is empty:

```
input=
while [[ $input = "" ]]; do
   read input
done
```

Comment: This has the (minor) problem of not handling ^D as end-of-input, so it will loop forever if it reads from `/dev/null`. That can be dealt with if you write it as `while read input && [ -z "$input" ]; do :; done`.

Comment: The loop would stuck if there's no input.

Answer (score 5):

```
unset input
while [ -z ${input} ]; do
     read input
done
```